# cakephp field() query error

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp-1.3, limit

I am trying to extract the latest `id` of the table called `gal_providers`

```
//get the id of the last gal_provider add.
$order = array("GalProvider.id DESC");
$gal_provider_id = $this->GalProvider->field("id",array("order"=>$order));
$this->data["User"]["username"] = "gal_provider_".$gal_provider_id;
```

But it shows error like :

> Warning (512): SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'order = ('GalProvider.id DESC')    LIMIT 1'
>   at line 1 [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]
>
> Query: SELECT `GalProvider`.`id` FROM `gal_providers` AS `GalProvider`
>   WHERE order = ('GalProvider.id DESC') LIMIT 1

Whats wrong with the code ?

Comment: Is `order` a column name in your table?

Comment: No..its for `order by id DESC`

Comment: Then you have a wrong `where` syntax.

Comment: Well I am confused since I am  new to `cake`. Basically I dont have a where condition. I just want to execute query  `SELECT id FROM gal_providers ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: [Cake PHP: Retrieving Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) should be helping you.

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
$order = array("GalProvider.id DESC");
```

to this:

```
$order = array('GalProvider.id' => 'desc');
```

or try this:

```
$gal_provider_id = $this->GalProvider->field("id",array('order' => array('GalProvider.id' => 'desc')));
```

Comment: Well now the query becomes `SELECT `GalProvider`.`id` FROM `gal_providers` AS `GalProvider`   WHERE order = ('desc')    LIMIT 1 ` and same error is showing !

Comment: :-( same error `SELECT `GalProvider`.`id` FROM `gal_providers` AS `GalProvider`   WHERE order = ('desc')    LIMIT 1 ` But I dont have a field called `order`. I just want to `order by desc desc limit 1`

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#field), the second argument of the Model::field() method is for a condition, and the third is for the order.

Also looking at the documentation, we can see that by default the condition and order arguments are null - which means we can do the same.

Try this:

```
$gal_provider_id = $this->GalProvider->field("id", null, "id DESC");
$this->data["User"]["username"] = "gal_provider_".$gal_provider_id;
```

In your example, you're using the Model::field() method as if it were the Model::find() method (they are two different methods and require different formats for their arguments)

Alternatively, we can use the find method itself:

```
$gal_provider = $this->GalProvider->find('first', array(
    'fields' => array('GalProvider.id'),
    'order' => 'GalProvider.id DESC',
    'recursive' => -1 // more efficient (ensures no joins made for the query)
));
$this->data["User"]["username"] = "gal_provider_".$gal_provider['GalProvider']['id'];
```